# Comparing percentiles of datasets of varying sizes

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, quantiles

I have a dataset with 100 observations. I calculate the 25th, 50th and 75th percentile of this dataset.

I have another dataset of new observations which contains about 10 values. I calculate the 25th, 50th and 75th percentile of this dataset as well.

Is it fair to say if the 25th, 50th and 75th percentile of `dataset2` are 25%(can be any number based on the level of sensitivity you desire) or more different than `dataset1`, then the observations in `dataset2` do not adhere to `dataset1`?

**Update**

`Dataset1` has requests made to a website in a day. Below is a sample,

```
Time between requests (ms)
     393.0
    7354.0
     760.0
67724213.0
    1443.0
```

`Dataset2` has requests made to the same website in a 15 min time span. For example, from 8.15am to 8.30am the next day.

I take the `np.percentile` of `dataset1` and the `np.percentile` of `dataset2`. I want to detect if there is an anomaly in `dataset2`. For example, if no requests were made to the website in the 15 min time span (from 8.15 - 8.30am), maybe there is a problem with the website (maybe it is unresponsive). On the other hand, if the time span between requests was 1ms or less, `np.percentile` of `dataset2` will deviate from `dataset1`, and that will suggest maybe we are under a DOS attack.

Below are my questions -

1) Is it mathematically correct to compare percentiles of datasets with varying sizes?

2) Is this is a good approach if I am trying to build something simple.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures) will help?

Comment: Is there a reason you are limiting your statistics to just a few percentiles and these specific percentiles?  Why not use all the data to compare the datasets?  That is guaranteed to be a better approach.

Comment: 1. The precise intent of the phrase "observations [...] do not adhere" is unclear to me. Do you mean to ask whether the two are consistent with each sample having come from populations with the same distribution? 2. There's a common display that includes the percentiles you mention, the boxplot, and a rough comparison of medians that can be made using a slightly modified form (to see whether the sample medians are more different than would be consistent with them having the same population distribution.(a notched boxplot). If you want a more formal comparison, it's better to use all the data.

Comment: @Glen_b @whuber I am trying to build a simple anomaly detection system. So I am wondering if it is safe to say if percentiles of `dataset2` are far away from `dataset1`, observations in `dataset2` are anomalous.

Comment: "safe", "away from" and "anomalous" are just as vague as "adhere to". What sort of properties do you need?

Comment: @Glen_b I have updated the question. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: If your question is about monitoring a data stream for anomalously long intervals, then edit it to focus on that.  Explain your data and your objectives rather than what you think a solution might be.  Consider this analogy: a patient comes to a physician asking whether it's better to take mercury or apply leeches to cure their rash.  A modern physician would ignore that question in favor of examining the patient to find out the cause of the rash, and proceed from there.